# Plotly extensions install with jupyter lab version 0.34

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter-lab

In my corporate environment, I am limited to using jupyter lab version 0.34 and ipywidgets version 7.4.

I am trying to install the plotly jupyter lab extensions to have plotly express plots being rendered when using jupyter lab. To do so I followed the steps described here https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/. However they do not seem to work fine with my version of the two dependencies.

What should be the steps to install the extensions properly for jupyter lab 0.34?

See set up below.

```
 C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4) C:\Users\***>conda list jupyterlab
# packages in environment at C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4:
#
jupyterlab                0.34.12                  py36_0    defaults


(C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4) C:\Users\***>conda list plotly
# packages in environment at C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4:
#

plotly                    4.1.0                      py_0    plotly
plotly_express            0.4.1                      py_0    plotly

(C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4) C:\Users\***>conda list ipywidgets
# packages in environment at C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4:
#

ipywidgets                7.4.2                    py36_0    defaults

(C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4) C:\Users\***>jupyter labextension list
JupyterLab v0.34.12
Known labextensions:

   app dir: C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4\share\jupyter\lab
    @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v0.37.4 enabled  ok
    jupyterlab-chart-editor v1.2.0 enabled  ok
    jupyterlab-plotly v1.1.0 enabled  ok
    plotlywidget v1.1.0 enabled  ok


Build recommended, please run `jupyter lab build`:

    @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager needs to be included in build
    plotlywidget needs to be included in build    
    jupyterlab-chart-editor needs to be included in build    
    jupyterlab-plotly needs to be included in build
```

See error message when building

```
(C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4) C:\Users\***>jupyter lab build

[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 0.34.12    
[LabBuildApp] Building in C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4\share\jupyter\lab    
[LabBuildApp] > node C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js install    
yarn install v1.9.4    
info No lockfile found.

[1/4] Resolving packages...

warning @jupyterlab/application > @jupyterlab/coreutils > comment-json > json-parser@1.1.5: `json-parser` is deprecated. Please use `comment-json` instead

warning @jupyterlab/application > @jupyterlab/apputils > react > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.

warning @jupyterlab/faq-extension@0.18.4: The JupyterLab FAQ extension is no longer developed and is removed from JupyterLab 1.0.

error Received malformed response from registry for undefined. The registry may be down.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

[LabBuildApp] > node C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3_4\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js run build

yarn run v1.9.4

$ webpack

'webpack' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```